# MVC Class between controller and Model

Tags: php, model-view-controller, phalcon

I'm building application in Phalcon PHP where I have database with access from website and API.

In normal website I would create MVC like here:

```
- app
-- controllers
-- models
-- views
- public
```

but I have problem with duplicate code for API and Web.

Sample code:

```
class Users extends Model {
    // ...
    protected $id;
    protected $username;
    protected $email;
    // setters and getters, validation
}

class UserController extends ControllerBase {
    // ...
    public function loginAction() {
        if ($this->request->isPost()) {
            // ... get post
            // check login is correct
            // create session
            // redirect
        }
        $this->view->var = $var;
    }
}

class ApiController extends ControllerBase {
    // ...
    public function loginAction() {
        if ($this->request->isPost() //or put) {
            $json = $this->request->getJsonRawBody();
            // ... get json
            // check login is correct
            // create session
        }
        $response->setStatusCode('2xx/4xx', 'msg');
        $response->setJsonContent([
            'status' => 'OK / ERROR',
            'message' => '$msg / $ex->getMessage()'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Now I would create class with logic for check is user data correct.
I think about class like this:

```
class MyClass extends ParentClass {
    public function login($username, $password) {
        $user = Users::findFirstByEmail($email);
        if ($user->password === hash($password)) {
            $successLogin = new UserSuccessLogins();
            $successLogin ->setId('id');
            $successLogin ->setIpAddress('ip');
            $successLogin ->save();
        } else {
            $failedLogin = new UserFailedLogins();
            $failedLogin->setId('id');
            $failedLogin->setIpAddress('ip');
            $failedLogin->save();
        }
    }
}
```

And now I could use it in controllers like here:

```
class UserController extends ControllerBase {
    public function loginAction() {
        if ($this->request->isPost()) {
            $c = new MyClass();
            if ($c->login($username, $password)) {
                // redirect
            } 
        }
        $this->view->var = $var;
    }
}

class ApiController extends ControllerBase {
    public function loginAction() {
        if ($this->request->isPost() //or put) {
            $c = new MyClass();
            if ($c->login($username, $password)) {
                // send json OK
            } else {
                // send json Error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is best way for this? I don't want logic in model class.
I have read about Plugin and Component, but I don't know how create good self commented code.

Comment: I have an MVC Architecture for my class and the way I handle user authentication is in the Users class. To be clear, there is a User class (with id, username, email, ect) and then the Users class. The plural classes (Users) does all the work with creating, deleting, authenticating users while the User class is just a model. Does that help?

Comment: @ChadK: yes, it may be good way to solve my problem, but creating, deleting, etc methods are preimplemented with Pahlcon framework in Model class. Of course I'll have a lot of model classes with needed some logic and I wouldn't create controller objects in other controllers.

Comment: Any particular reason you have an API Controller with the login function and the UserController with a login function? Or is that what you're trying to fix? What's the difference between the two controllers?

Comment: It's just simple example. In my application I need other logic functions and with website I need return view, but with API only json. With website user can login, and make some actions, but I'd like create mobile application with access to same database.

Comment: Controllers are *supposed* to only handle data, and not display it. Views are typically accessed via a redirect (POST Redirect GET method). So In your case, I would make both the API Controller just delegate the request to the proper controller and then return the result, rather than have two separate controllers

Comment: You are right about controllers, but in Phalcon framework, you have simple access to view just from controller. So I get a post data, make any action, send variables to view and that's all. But sometimes instand of send data to view I'd like set json header and send json string from same controllerAction(). I know I can check isAjax() or isPost() but I'd like to have clean code instand of many lines in one function.

Comment: You are right about using `Component`. In your `MyClass` just extend the `Component` class i.e. `class MyClass extends Component { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for Phalcon Multimodule, have a look at [this example](https://github.com/phalcon/mvc/tree/master/multiple). Besides "Front-End" and "Back-End" modules, you can add "API" module.

Comment: It's not exactly what I'm looking, but seems very interesting. Thx for your answer.

Comment: It's fascinating. Also, you can architecture your app to have an extra "Common" module to share between API and Back-End (and API can be Micro and Back-End full MVC).

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm going to extend my project with components like here:

```
-app
--components
--controllers
--models
--views
-public
```

Now, my code may looks like below:

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;
class Users extends Model {
    // ...
    protected $id;
    protected $username;
    protected $email;
    // setters and getters, validation
}

use Phalcon\Mvc\User\Component;
class UserComponent extends Component {
    // class with access to dependecy injector
    public login ($email, $password) {
        $user = Users::findFirstByEmail($email);
        // logic with setting session in $di
    }
}

class UserController extends ControllerBase {
    public function loginAction() {
        if ($this->request->isPost()) {
            $userComponent = new UserComponent();
            if ($userComponent ->login($username, $password)) {
                return $this->response->redirect($this->url->getBaseUri(), false, 301);
            } else {
                $this->flash->error('message');
            }
        }
        // setting view variables if not post or login filed
        $this->view->var = $var;
    }
}


class ApiController extends ControllerBase {
    public function loginAction() {
        if ($this->request->isPost()) {
            $userComponent = new UserComponent();
            if ($userComponent ->login($username, $password)) {
                //json OK
            } else {
                //json Error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If no one have better proposition I'll close this topic as solved in few days.

Answer (score 0):

Your suggestion is a good option, however if you want to decouple and segregate responsibilities in a better way, you can try to use a service layer like in this example https://github.com/phalcon/mvc/tree/master/multiple-service-layer-model. Where you will have:

- entities ( the models generated by phalcon)
- repositories ( all the operations that requires fetching, updating or persisting data)
- services (where the business logic is).

Whit this the call graph can be summarised as follow:

controllers -> services -> repositories -> entities

Note that the dependencies go in a single direction, nonetheless for simple tasks you can use a repo inside the controller directly o a entity inside the service, is up to you how hard or flexible your architecture will be.

I hope It is clear regards.